# Make a variable available throughout a spec.js file

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a test spec file whose purpose is to check for a booking reference in our application then check that the same reference is quoted in an email.

In the first part of the test I declare a variable called `dbmRef` - I know this is working as I've got a `console.log` that shows the contents of the variable.

Further down- on in the email system (Outlook.com), I have another variable called `dbm` that finds the booking ref in the email body.

Finally, I have `expect(dbm).toContain(dbmRef)` but this errors with `Expected 'DBM040815' to contain undefined.`

I'm assuming that Protractor cannot 'see' the first variable from further up the script...is that right? If so, how can I remedy please?

Herewith the code - not in final form!

```
/**********************
 * Company: Guestline
 * Product: DBM
 * Author: D Redmayne
 **********************/

var hotKeys = require('protractor-hotkeys');

describe('DBM Hotel', function() {

  it('Confirmation', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.sleep(500);

    // assertions
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('| Confirmation');

    var conf1 = element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/h4")).getText();
    expect(conf1).toContain("DBM");

    var conf2 = element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span/span/span")).getText();
    expect(conf2).toContain("£50.00");

    var dbmRef = element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/h4")).getText().then(console.log);

    // allows time for Outlook to capture email
    browser.sleep(2000);
    browser.get('https://outlook.com/');
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.sleep(10000);

    //chooses sign-in
    element(by.xpath("html/body/section/div/div/nav/div/div/div/a")).click();
    browser.sleep(500);
    // enters credentials
    element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='i0116']")).sendKeys('xxxxxx@outlook.com');
    browser.sleep(1000);
    element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='idSIButton9']")).click();
    browser.sleep(500);
    element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='i0118']")).sendKeys('pppppppp');
    element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='idSIButton9']")).click();
    browser.sleep(300);
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Mail - David Redmayne - Outlook');
    browser.sleep(10000);

    element(by.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div")).click();
    browser.sleep(500);

    var dbm = element(by.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/b")).getText();
    expect(dbm).toContain(dbmRef);
  });
});
```

Comment: where do you declare the variable, what's the scope of a variable? it's nothing related to protractor

Comment: Here's the code - not in final condition!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question is simple, you just define your variable outside of `describe` like this

```
let myVar;

describe('DBM Hotel', function () {

  it('Confirmation', function () {
    console.log(myVar); // undefined
    myVar = "value";
  });

  it('Confirmation', function () {
    console.log(myVar); // value
  });
});
```

Not sure why it doesn't work inside of `describe`, but I assume because of how Jasmine works, which 'parses' describe with all its `it` blocks when browser isn't open yet.

**BUT THIS IS NOT YOUR PROBLEM**, because you do everything inside of same `it` block. Essentially you have bunch of problems. Your main issue is how you het variable

```
var dbmRef = element(by.xpath("xpath")).getText().then(console.log);
```

What this means is

```
var dbmRef = element(by.xpath("xpath")).getText().then(
  function(value) {
    console.log(value)
  }
);
```

You log your text, but the function still returns `undefined` by default, to change that you just need to add return statement like so

```
var dbmRef = element(by.xpath("xpath")).getText().then(
  function(value) {
    console.log(value);
    return value
  }
);
```

That's one way. Another way is

```
let dbmRef;

describe('DBM Hotel', function () {

  it('Confirmation', function () {
  // ...
    element(by.xpath("xpath")).getText().then(
      function(value) {
        dbmRef = value
      }
    );
  // ...
  });
});
```

You have to understand Promises to use this syntax. And finally the best way is this

```
it('Confirmation', async function () {
  // ...
  dbmRef = await element(by.xpath("xpath")).getText();
  // ...
});
```

But it requires `await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)` and some knowledge about `async/await` keywords. But it's a lot easier to understand them then Promises, so I highly recommend to spend a day and read all about it

And lastly I'll mention a few other problems in your code

```
// #1
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.sleep(500);

expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('| Confirmation');

// #2
var conf1 = element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/h4")).getText();
expect(conf1).toContain("DBM");

var conf2 = element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span/span/span")).getText();
expect(conf2).toContain("£50.00");
// #3
var dbmRef = element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/h4")).getText().then(console.log);

browser.sleep(2000);
browser.get('https://outlook.com/');
// #4
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.sleep(10000);

element(by.xpath("html/body/section/div/div/nav/div/div/div/a")).click();
browser.sleep(500);


element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='i0116']")).sendKeys('xxxxxx@outlook.com');
browser.sleep(1000);
element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='idSIButton9']")).click();
browser.sleep(500);
element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='i0118']")).sendKeys('pppppppp');
element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='idSIButton9']")).click();
browser.sleep(300);
expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Mail - David Redmayne - Outlook');
browser.sleep(10000);

element(by.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div")).click();
browser.sleep(500);

// #5
var dbm = element(by.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/b")).getText();
expect(dbm).toContain(dbmRef);
```

#1 if you use Protractor 5 and higher this command is deprecated

#2 the command may not work at times, because of how promises work

#3 is your main problem, I already explained

#4 duplicate command, you don't need it

#5 don't use these long xpath, they'll be breaking every day

Comment: thank you very much - there's a lot of useful info there!!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, AZ_ is right this question is related to the [javascript variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).

However, the solution is that you could initialize variables outside the `it` block.

**UPDATED:**

```
    describe('DBM Hotel', function () {
      var dbmRef;

      it('Confirmation', function () {
        // ...
        element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/h4")).getText().then(text => {
          dbmRef = text;
        });

        // ...
        var dbm = element(by.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/b")).getText();
        expect(dbm).toContain(dbmRef);
      });
    });
```

Comment: thanks both - I've included the scripts but I'll try the above in the meantime.

Comment: @sergey - still having issues - please do post your suggestions. Thanks